# Sharing on Google+ with big image (photo sharing, perhaps)?

Tags: google-plus

I'm currently working on a Google Hangouts app that, among other things, features posting links to certain pages on the user's Google+ page.
Because the shared content is mainly a visual thing (dynamically generated images, to be precise), I have been looking at ways of having the post
on user's stream display a big, full-width picture, essentially an effect similar to [one visible here](https://plus.google.com/115900903196483234016/posts/LgCoqHAbe4v) (disclaimer: I do not endorse the company linked in any way, it was simply one of the first examples I have found of the look).

Now, I've read through Google+ documentation on Share Button and Snippets about ways to have sharing from a single click and customisation of the content that comes with the link, but visually, the attached thumbnail is somewhat smaller than what I'd find ideal for the task (as visible [image: on this screenshot]).
The example of a big picture display was tied to the photo sharing functionality, so I've looked at Google+ API, to see if there's a way to automate it, but as stated on [the API docs landing page](https://developers.google.com/+/api/), "The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data.". No ability to pursue the goal through the official channels then.
Next step, GitHub. There are some sites for which the wrappers around their internal communication have been written, thus creating sort of unofficial API, so I tried my luck there. Among various libraries, I have found one that was not a wrapper around an official API, [google-plus-extension-jsapi](https://github.com/mohamedmansour/google-plus-extension-jsapi/), but being written for the context of Chrome extensions rather than webpages, I couldn't get it to work, mainly due to usage of WebSQL and cross-domain XMLHTTPRequests.

Without any further leads, I ask the community thus - is there any way for a webpage app to provide the user with the ability to share a full-width picture on their Google+ stream or am I limited to standard sharing thumbnails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will confirm, you can not do what you're trying to do using the Google+ API because there is no stream write API and you do not have control over how shares will render.

As you have already determined, you can not write posts, such as a picture, directly to a user's stream, without the user's interaction (e.g. share). For branded pages, there is [the Pages API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup), but it is currently not public and would be restricted to Pages as opposed to People/Profiles.

You can generate a share link to an external image and then if the user clicks it, the image can appear in their stream. As you noticed, the image will be a small thumbnail as opposed to a full-bleed photo and will render as a share - undesirable if you want the image to fill the whole stream area.