# Google plus api : Share image

Tags: google-plus

Is there any way to share images with description using Google+ public api?
For facebook I use

```
FB.api('me/images', 'post', {
   message: 'My description - http://www.mywebsite.com/mypage',
   url: 'http://www.mywebsite.com/path/to/my/image.jpg'
   }, function (r) {
    alert('SUCCESS');
 });
```

For Google+, I juste have

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://www.mywebsite.com/mypage
```

but this just gives a small capture of the image with the information contained in the open graph tags. I want something that gives the same result as if you clic on "Photos" on Google+ and then drag & drop an image then add a description.
Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing on Google+ with big image (photo sharing, perhaps)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324834/sharing-on-google-with-big-image-photo-sharing-perhaps)